# Issue trying to pull in all cities/towns for a zip code using google api

Tags: java, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the google maps api to check an address users add by passing the zip code and returning a formatted address that I can compare to see if it matches.
This is the call:

```
resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

The problem is some zipcode can be a part of mutiple cities/towns.
Here is the result for the google api for zip code 77380:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<type>postal_code</type>
<formatted_address>Spring, TX 77380, USA</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>77380</long_name>
<short_name>77380</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Spring</long_name>
<short_name>Spring</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Texas</long_name>
<short_name>TX</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>United States</long_name>
<short_name>US</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>...</geometry>
<postcode_locality>Shenandoah</postcode_locality>
<postcode_locality>Spring</postcode_locality>
<postcode_locality>The Woodlands</postcode_locality>
<place_id>ChIJUXEWvwI0R4YRWJe_Gb6C8Bk</place_id>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

The user in this example lives in The Woodlands TX, not Spring TX. 
What I'm trying to do now is pull in the postcode_locality so that I can compare any of the cities/towns listed  (Shenandoah, Spring,The Woodlands)

I tired doing this :

```
resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result/postcode_locality", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

but I only got back Shenandoah.
I can do /GeocodeResponse/result/postcode_locality[1] and get each location manually but this code needs to work for any zip code entered.

Is there a way pull in a list of postcode_locality?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:

```
    Element e = (Element) node;
    NodeList resultNodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("postcode_locality");
```

This might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I'm extracting the results from google api with resultNodeList, so I don't have the node yet. I actually found a solution and posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

I think my proposed solution was too complicated. I fixed my issue by passing city name with zipcode.

```
private static final String GEOCODER_REQUEST = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";
.
.
.
URL url = new URL( GEOCODER_REQUEST + "?address=" +address.getZip()+address.getCity().replaceAll("\\s+","%20"));
```

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=77380%20Woodlands

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<type>postal_code</type>
<formatted_address>The Woodlands, TX 77380, USA</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>77380</long_name>
<short_name>77380</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>The Woodlands</long_name>
<short_name>The Woodlands</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Texas</long_name>
<short_name>TX</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>United States</long_name>
<short_name>US</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>30.1261952</lat>
<lng>-95.4672962</lng>
</location>
<location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
<viewport>
<southwest>
<lat>30.1032280</lat>
<lng>-95.5058700</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>30.1782430</lat>
<lng>-95.4368399</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
<bounds>
<southwest>
<lat>30.1032280</lat>
<lng>-95.5058700</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>30.1782430</lat>
<lng>-95.4368399</lng>
</northeast>
</bounds>
</geometry>
<partial_match>true</partial_match>
<place_id>ChIJUXEWvwI0R4YRWJe_Gb6C8Bk</place_id>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

This gives a more accurate formatted_address.